# Install mozroot-certdata package on a read only root file system

Tags: mono, ssl-certificate, embedded-linux, yocto

I have an established yocto build which I'm now trying to switch over to having a root file system (eg. `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "read-only-rootfs"`).

However I'm running into an issue with a recipe in the meta-mono layer: mozroot-certdata. I see the culprit is the pkg_postint script (http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-mono/tree/recipes-mono/mozroot-certdata/mozroot-certdata_1.0.0.bb) which needs to modify the root file system on first boot which the build system is correctly flagging as impossible with a read only root file system:

```
ERROR: The following packages could not be configured offline and rootfs is read-only: ['mozroot-certdata']
```

My question is: is there a way to get these mozroot certs installed and configured with mono during the build process, such that the root file system does not need to be modified at boot/run time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I had a brief look at this late this summer, as I'm also using a read-only rootfs. The problem is that `mozroot.exe` is hardcoded to write into `/usr/share/.mono/certs` and does not respect your sysroot. You could probably hack `mozroot.exe` to actually write the imported files into the sysroot, though my time limit didn't allow me to try this (and neither have I ever looked into `mono` at all...).

My solution was instead to do the import at every boot. (It could also be done only once, but then the issue about updates come along). To achive this I made a bind mount on the directory where `mozroot.exe` wants to write the certdata.

**Details of my solution**

Add a file `volatile-binds.bbappend` with the following contents:

```
VOLATILE_BINDS += "\
    /tmp/mono-certs /usr/share/.mono/certs \n\
"
```

That will make a bind mount from `/tmp/mono-certs` to `/usr/share/.mono/certs`, thus you'll be able to import the certs.

Then I added a service file and a `mozroot-certdata_%.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${BPN}:"

DEPENDS += "mono-native"

SRC_URI += "file://mozroot-certdata.service \
"

inherit systemd

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mozroot-certdata.service"

do_install_append() {
    mkdir -p ${D}${datadir}/.mono/certs
    mkdir -p ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}
    install -m 440 ${WORKDIR}/mozroot-certdata.service ${D}${systemd_system_unitdir}/mozroot-certdata.service
}

FILES_${PN} += "${datadir}"

# Empty the postinstallation script, as we can import the cert offline.
pkg_postinst_${PN} () {
#     mono $D/usr/lib/mono/4.5/mozroots.exe --import --machine --ask remove --file $D/${sysconfdir}/ssl/certdata.txt
}
```

The service file `mozroot-certdata.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Import certficates to Mono
After=tmp-mono-certs.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mozroots.exe --import --machine --ask-remove --file /etc/ssl/certdata.txt

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to get these mozroot certs installed and configured with mono during the build process

Yes but it requires mosroots binary to be executable at rootfs creation time. See [Post-Installation Scripts](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#post-installation-scripts) in documentation.

The 'else' branch in pkg_postinst is what gets executed at that time and if it succeeds, then the delayed postinst is not needed (and you shouldn't get a build error). `mono-native` recipe already exists so you should be able to depend on that and to fix the else branch in the `pkg_postinst` function so it finds native mono & mosroots.exe and writes to the correct place under $D.

As Anders mentioned this alone is not enough if you care about package-based upgrades.

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer, mozroot.exe tried to write to `/usr/share/.mono/certs` on my own machine... Thus, I don't believe that this currently works during rootfs creation time. You'll likely need to patch `mono-native` to handle that.

Comment: Thanks. In that case a patch for mosroots.exe would be needed -- I'm sure mono upstream would accept a "--certdir" option or something like that as well